# WiX changing size of default UI elements

Tags: wix

given this snippet:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp"
             Value="logo.bmp"/>
<WixVariable Id ="WixUIBannerBmp"
              Value="banner.bmp"/>            
<UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"
               Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
     <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>         
</UI>
```

is there a way to specify the width and height for "logo.bmp" and "banner.bmp" in the .wxs file without without creating a custom dialog or modifying the wixui extension?  If there is, where would should I have looked to find out?

I have a number of installations from another, inferior tool for which the art assets have already been finalized, and I'd like to use them in my WiX installers with minimal pain.

Thanks :)

Ben Brammer

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible in the current version of WiX. In a future release, it will be possible using localization support to adjust the image controls' size and location.

Update: The future is now. WiX v3.6 lets localization override size and location of controls and dialogs. [See my blog for details.](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/)